# Handling Message and CommandInteraction types in Discord slash commands with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I have a discord bot with a decent number of commands. It slowly grew from a very small codebase in Java and has formed into a somewhat OK Typescript/discord.js project over the years. However, it never came time to convert the commands into the not-so-new-anymore slash commands that Discord released. Partly because it just doesn't fit the theme of the bot. But now there are a couple of commands, that have a very hard-to-nail-down syntax, so I decided to also give them a slash command. But when I tried to extend my type for the commands I came to a halt.

Here are some important lines from my `types.ts` file:

```js
type RunFunction = (message: Message, arg: string) => Awaitable<string | MessagePayload | MessageCreateOptions | void>;

type Command = {
  run: string | RunFunction
}

type Module = {
  commands?: Record<string, RunFunction | Command | string>
}
```

Currently, I have a couple of typescript files in a folder called `modules`, where each file exports a `Module` object. The commands are indexed by their name in the `commands` object and the value can either be just a string of the literal response the bot will send back, `RunFunction` which executes when the command is called, or it can be a `Command` object which specifies a couple of non-required fields and a property `run` which should be clear what it does.

The problem is that the `RunFunction` takes a `Message` object as a parameter, which does not exist when dealing with interactions.

My first thought was to include another property in `Command` called `acceptsInteraction` which would tell typescript, that `run` is a function accepting both types like this:

```js
type Command = {
  acceptsInteraction: true;
  run: (interactionOrMessage: CommandInteraction | Message, arguments?: string) => Awaitable<string | MessagePayload | MessageCreateOptions | void>;
} | {
  acceptsInteraction?: false;
  run: RunFunction;
}
```

And this worked when I created a test command outside of everything like this:

```js
const test1: Command = {
  run: (mes, arg) => {}
}
```

VSCode nicely shows the correct types of `mes` and `arg` even when I add or remove the property `acceptsInteraction`.

But the problem starts to show up when I try to use the whole `Module` object. For some reason typescript doesn't like this code:

```js
const test2: Module = {
  commands: {
    testcmd: {
      run: (mes, arg) => {}
    }
  }
}
```

It says that parameters `mes` and `arg` implicitly have 'any' type. Why?

The only way I was able to get around this weird issue was to remove other possible types of `commands` like that:

```js
type Module = {
  commands?: Record<string, Command>
}
```

With the module defined like this VSCode again shows the correct types for those parameters. But that is not what I was looking for.

If you think that this approach is bad and you have a better idea that fits my needs, feel free to share your opinion.

Just to be clear, I want to convert only some commands to accept the slash command and thus this problem.

Also here is a [typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?pretty=true&ts=4.9.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIQM4bgcxQbwChlkEALOEECAGwC5kiSSMIQATBgCgQHtw2YBhjBRQOAJTIAvAD5kABSi8AtsFYAedFlwRZxZAF9Cx0JFiIUAYVUrK7AJICoiMMH6MDUCAAcaAT25eHzd+DAZKfyk5RWU1TUj9Y0Iwfx8UACUAVxAAMRyEUJAZZC4VTGw8Bm1KiAAaZDgoHHDkETEQSRl5ADdeYHYAbkIUtOtbexKmRoQkEIwnc1d3EAZRLIhhkigc7jNoZf4AeSga3QYbFTsORYPCleQAHzQK3QamnAB+YVFxaN7+kMTE9PCREHMwAtnIcQN9kPAaKwtsgdqtkNk8gUisNkql0mheOwsjQUNJQaQJhwMHCMhA+FB2Bp2uIGhj8iB7h5npdruwQczOkkRnwQCJkJARABGC6Uvlk6ao7jlDDvZr-RjGZIisUSsAAJmqhOJpPJfCu9la0xIuoQKk45OYKN2pWVqq6MXwRgMJGMPpMQA) in case it helps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across a similar issue when trying to type-define my slash commands and such.

This is what I found works for me:

```
export type SlashCommand = {
    data: RESTPostAPIChatInputApplicationCommandsJSONBody | Omit<SlashCommandBuilder, "addSubcommandGroup" | "addSubcommand">
    | SlashCommandSubcommandsOnlyBuilder;
    userPermissions: Array<bigint>;
    botPermissions: Array<bigint>;
    run: (client: Client, interaction: ChatInputCommandInteraction) => Promise<any>;
}
```

Then I have my commands set up like:

```
const commandName: SlashCommand = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("commandName")
        .setDescription("description")
        .setDMPermission(false)
    ),
    userPermissions: [],
    botPermissions: [],
    run: async (client, interaction) => {
        //...
    },
}
```

However, things I've run into:

- When adding subcommands `.addSubcommand()` I must end the `data` parameter with `.toJSON()` (hence the `RESTPostAPIChatInputApplicationCommandsJSONBody` type within `data`)
- I also just can't figure out how to get sub command groups to work and pares properly... But I'm sure it's a simple fix I'm not finding.

Thought I'd share my make-shift solution since there's not an answer here yet.

Comment: Here's what I use: `SlashCommandBuilder | SlashCommandSubcommandsOnlyBuilder | Omit<SlashCommandBuilder, "addSubcommand" | "addSubcommandGroup">` works perfectly

Comment: @Elitezen,

I get an error with that, `ValidationError: Expected a string primitive` any ideas why?

Comment: That's an error based on supplied values to the builder, not with the typings. One of your builder methods expected a string but got something else.

Comment: I set it to `RESTPostAPIChatInputApplicationCommandsJSONBody | SlashCommandBuilder | SlashCommandSubcommandsOnlyBuilder | SlashCommandSubcommandGroupBuilder | Omit<SlashCommandBuilder, "addSubcommand" | "addSubcommandGroup">`. Now when I add sub-commands and/or sub-command groups I end it with `.toJSON()` and it works :)